# CakePHP ACL/ACO errors

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I get the following error when viewing my home page for my CakePHP website:

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => admin@test.com
            [group_id] => 1
            [created] => 2008-07-05 17:16:58
            [modified] => 2008-07-05 17:16:58
        )

)

Aco: controllers/Pages/display [CORE/cake/libs/controller/components/acl.php, line 273]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/cameron/Sites/cakeapp/cake/libs/debugger.php:673) [CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 742]
```

What is the problem(s)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, did you create the ACO/ACL tables in the database. (usually in /config/sql). Next, your user probably needs the ACO/ACL foreign keys, so you'll probably have to modify your user table.

see this tutorial for more information:

http://lemoncake.wordpress.com/category/authorization/

Comment: Yes I have created the tables, I'm using the code from this tutorial: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/auth-and-acl-an-end-to-end-tutorial-pt-2

Comment: interesting...It's using behaviors to tie the ACO/ACL functionality to your group model. It seems like the User model and the Group model need to override the 'parentNode' function. If you look at the code in cake/libs/model/behaviors/AclBehavior.setup() it checks for that function.

Comment: The User doesn't need the foreign keys - this is handled by the Aro. The User, correctly, has the foreign key pointing to the Group.

Answer (score 0):

I recall getting errors like this, but unfortunately can't remember specific solutions. It came down to perseverance and tweaking. Try debug() on everything you can think of and you'll begin to get the picture.

If you followed the tutorial I posted earlier, start it again, double checking everything. It isn't a straightforward component/behaviour but Mark documents it well.

Stick with it!